# Picking two cards of the same suit

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So, I am having a problem with this in that the method I use gives two completely separate answers.

> Two cards are selected from a deck of $52$ playing cards.  What is the probability they constitute a pair (that is, that they are of the same denomination)?

So, for the first method I reason this.

The first card picked has a $13/52$ chance of being in some suit.  The second card picked has probability $12/51$ of being in the same suit.

So...  The probability should be $(13/52)(12/52) = 3/52$.

The other method is by combinatorics.

I have $52 \cdot 51$ one ways of creating a pair of cards.  But I have $13 \cdot 12$ different ways of creating a pair of the same suit.  Now to me, the logical thing to do is to multiply this number by $4$, because I would have to count each valid pair from each suit.

This would give me

$$\frac{4 \cdot 12 \cdot 13}{52 \cdot 51}$$

What's wrong with the reasoning on the second one?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?  I see your attempts, but I don't actually see a statement of the problem anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is this,  Two Cards are selected from a deck of 52 playing cards.  What is the probability they constitute a pair (That is, that they are of the same denomination?)

Comment: You appear to be trying to find two cards that are of the same *suit*, but you just asked about the probability of the two cards having the same *denomination* (i.e. the same value); which is it?

Comment: Ahhhh, I figured denomination was implying of the same suit.  Okay this makes more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The second is correct.

The first should be amended as follows. The first card has a chance of 1 of being in some suit, and the second should be 12/51 to be of the same suit, so the total is 12/51...

**UPDATE**

If the suit is fixed ahead of time, i.e. you need the probability to draw 2 hearts, not any 2 of the same suit, then first probability is 13/52 and second is 12/51, so indeed the total is $$\frac{13}{52} \times \frac{12}{51} = \frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{17} \approx 5.88\%$$

Comment: So, that is what I thought, but the book said it was the first.

Comment: @user3210277 see update